# opening mp4 via php results in full download before playback

Tags: php, flash, video, fopen, mp4

I'm trying to feed an mp4 file to flash player via php and the video is downloaded completely before starting playback.

```
$src = '/var/www/user/data/www/domain.com/video.mp4';
if(file_exists($src) and is_readable($src)) {
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($src));
    readfile($src);
} else die('error');
```

I've tried curl with similar results. Any ideas what's causing this delay?

Comment: When you say "similar results" do you mean that cURL takes ~20 seconds before returning any output as well?

Comment: Yes, the video is downloaded before it starts playback. If I open the mp4 file directly in firefox, it's being played in it's built-in video player right away. This doesn't happen when opening the php directly (100% download before it's displayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your Flash player is hoping you'll handle HTTP `Range` requests so it can get started faster on the playback.

The HTML5/Flash audio player [jPlayer has a section in their developer guide about this](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response). Scroll to the part about Byte-Range Requests:

> Your server must enable Range requests. This is easy to check for by
>   seeing if your server's response includes the Accept-Ranges in its
>   header.

Also note that they offer a PHP solution for handling `Range` requests if you have to use PHP instead of a direct download.

**smartReadFile.php**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jplayer/nSM2UmnSKKA/bC-l3k0pCPMJ

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction, but the video still loads fully before starting playback.

Comment: My headers contain:

   HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
   Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
   Pragma: no-cache
   Accept-Ranges: bytes
   Content-Length: 9634096
   Content-Range: bytes 2671042-12305137/12305138
   Content-Disposition: inline; filename=video.mp4
   content-transfer-encoding: binary
   Last-Modified: Tue, 02 Oct 2012 18:12:28 +0100
   Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=98
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Content-Type: video/mp4

Comment: Turns out it was a metadata issue with the mp4 file as I tried a different one and it worked! I've implemented the smartReadFile function you suggested, so that's settled. Many thanks!

Comment: I was just reading your comments. I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to just have apache send the file it self as opposed to reading it in php and dumping it to the output using X-Sendfile.

First make sure apache is compiled with sendfile support then alter your output code to be:

```
header ('X-Sendfile: ' . $src);
header ('Content-Type:  video/mp4');
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
exit;
```

This is normally faster than doing it via PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this as well and same thing- full download before any playback.