# Skipping MP4 video

Tags: php, .net, ffmpeg, video-streaming, qt-faststart

I like to create the video player to show videos on my website. I made a video player in flash CS5 and actionscript3 to stream the videos on the website.

My videos are often flv or mp4 format.
In the flv files I use flvmdi app to inject the metadata to that ,and for skipping the flv file I use xmoov-php (video player can pass the keyframe number from flv metadat to xmoov-php to create the new flv file from passed keyframe  to the last flv keyframe,  and return the flv video file on the php header for flash video player to show the video ).

but about mp4 format in Xmoov-php wiki   it says: 
this file can't support the mp4 format to skiping...!!!
Now I need  skiping the mp4 files in my video player (I like my viewers  select a part of video before buffering  all video on their browser and play it ).

please give me a suggestion to skipping the mp4 file in the php or .net platform

Answer (score 0):

for read mp4 metadata you can use [getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)

for skipping see this pages help you

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=345230#p345230

[Reading mp4 files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797762/reading-mp4-files-with-php)

[opening mp4 via php results in full download before playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695586/opening-mp4-via-php-results-in-full-download-before-playback)

i read  [Xmoov](http://wiki.toomuchmedia.com/index.php/Xmoov-php) wiki.

> Note: xmoov-php does not support playback of .mp4 files. If you wish
>   to allow streaming for .mp4 files, we recommend that you use jwplayer
>   or flowplayer and install any necessary plugins for .mp4 playback.

that mean jwplayer or flowplayer support it by **Byte-Range Requests**